# Continuity of mapping function in derivative function

Tags: functions, continuity

I've got a problem with this prove. I  don't know how to start.

Prove that mapping which transforms the function to it's derivative is continuous.

Let $(a,b) \in \Bbb R$

$D: y \rightarrow Dy $

where $y \in C^1(a,b)$  and $Dy \in C^0(a,b)$

$C^1(a,b)$ is a space of functions once differentiable with a continuous derivative and  $C^0(a,b) $ is a space of continuous function.

As far as I understand

$C^1(a,b)$ and  $C^0(a,b) $ are Banach spaces with the scalar product

$(u,v)_m =\sum_{ \vert \alpha \vert \le m} (D^\alpha u,D^\alpha v)_{L^2(\Omega)}$

and the norm $ \Vert u \Vert_m = \sqrt{(u,u)_m}$

But I'm not sure that the norm and scalar product are correct. If the proof is possible with another norm, then can anybody show at least the method?

Comment: Which topologies are considered at the spaces $C^1(a,b)$ and $C^0(a,b)$?

Comment: As far as I understand this are Banach spaces.

Comment: Endowed with which norms?

Comment: I've updated the information.

Comment: Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.